# How to omit skipped Google slides in an exported PDF?

Tags: google-slides

When I use `Download as > PDF Document (.pdf)`, skipped slides are included in the PDF.

Is there any way to download a PDF without skipped slides?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, in another menu.

0. Click *File* in the Google Slides interface.
1. Go to *Print preview*.
2. Deselect *Include skipped slides*.
3. Click *Download as PDF*.

Comment: First step: 0. Go to File